# How to use a result outside the variable in which it was defined

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am defining a DataTable like this:

```
var yadcf_data_2;
var oTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {"url": "/platform/elements/?format=datatables",
           "dataSrc": function(json){
             yadcf_data_2 = json.options.yadcf_data_2
             console.log(yadcf_data_2)
             return json.data;
            }
          }
```

How would I use `yadcf_data_2` outside of the variable in which it was defined, like this?

```
yadcf.exRefreshColumnFilterWithDataProp(oTable, 3, yadcf_data_2);
```

Comment: You'll need to include it as part of your return, OR, define the variable at the scope where you need it

Comment: could you please provide an example?

Comment: `var yadcf_data_2; var oTable = ...` (so you're declaring the variable outside of the scope of the ajax call).

Comment: I actually have that already (just added to the question), but a `console.log(yadcf_data_2)` outside of `var oTable = ` results in `undefined`

Comment: That means a value hasn't yet been assigned...or was assigned as undefined

Comment: but `console.log(yadcf_data2` within the `oTable` declaration prints the list of values appropriately

Comment: Timing is everything....

Comment: I know - that's why I'm trying to understand how to reference yadcf_data_2 outside of the variable appropriately. I understand it's because of the asynchronous nature, but I'm having trouble applying the answer in the other question to my code